# what is the difference between kafka consumer concurrency and @Async?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am really confused about this,is there any difference between these codes.

1.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic", concurrency = "2")
public void consumer(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack){
}
```

2. @KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic")
   public void consumer(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack){
   }

   @KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic")
   public void consumer2(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack){
   }

additionally,another confusion as belowed.

How does @Async works with the code?

1.

```
@Async("taskExecutor")
@KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic")
public void consumer2(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack){
}
```

2. @Async("taskExecutor")
   @KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic", concurrency = "2")
   public void consumer2(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack){
   }

Comment: The listener would already be asynchronous, but maybe adding will associate with a specific executor? The concurrency simply starts N separate threads that all have the same function body... If you want to do different things on a topic, use different methods (but with a different group.id)